# How to stop bootstrap overriding css classes in angular?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have installed bootstrap in my angular app but not imported in anywhere in my app like style.css or index.html.

But I am seeing bootstrap is working fine in my app and overriding some of my css classes. Is there any way to stop bootstrap from override my class.

I want to use bootstrap only in which component it has been imported.

Comment: Have you checked your `angular.json`? `styles` property.

Comment: Thank you @LiuZhang . It was my mistake  that bootstrap was in the angular.json. But why it has been applied globally? Is there any way to make it component based.

Comment: Or is there any way to restrict bootstrap from override component css class?

Comment: I guess you've installed bootstrap using `ng add` command, and it will update angular.json automatically. And bootstrap should be applied globally. If you really want that, you need to import bootstrap.css on each component which is kinda bad practice. I would say you've chosen the wrong way.